# Custom KnockoutJS bindingHandler for dynamic Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I've found a couple other questions and resources here on using Bootstrap tooltips with a custom knockout binding handler.  However, I haven't found is a cohesive solution that 1) involves using a dynamic knockout template 2) one where the tooltip can change when data it is bound to changes.

I'm also away of [knockout-bootstrap](https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap) on GitHub, but the tooltip title in that is rendered only once,

I've created a NEW [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tMbs5/9/) with the following new dynamicTooltip that's based on the prior [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BF5yW/).

The new DynamicTooltip data binder looks like:

```
ko.renderTemplateHtml = function (templateId, data) {
    var node = $("<div />")[0];
    ko.renderTemplate(templateId, data, {}, node);
    return $(node).html();
};

ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var local = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        options = {};

    ko.utils.extend(options, ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.options);
    ko.utils.extend(options, local);

    var tmplId = options.kotemplate;

    ko.utils.extend(options, {
        title: ko.renderTemplateHtml(tmplId, viewModel)
    });

    $(element).tooltip(options);

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).tooltip("destroy");
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var local = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        options = {};

    ko.utils.extend(options, ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.options);
    ko.utils.extend(options, local);

    var tmplId = options.kotemplate;
    var forceRefresh = options.forceRefresh;
    var newdata =  ko.renderTemplateHtml(tmplId, viewModel); 
    $(element).data('bs.tooltip').options.title = newdata

},
options: {
    placement: "top",
    trigger: "hover",
    html: true
}};
```

It's not complete, as I'm manually triggering the update call manually by passing in a dummy databinding property on the view Model, in this case, it's called renderTooltip():

```
<a data-bind="tooltip: { title: firstName, placement: 'bottom', kotemplate: 'tile-tooltip-template', forceRefresh: renderTooltip() }">Hover on me</a>
```

I'd like to be able to trigger the tooltip to refresh itself when data changes.

I'm thinking I should be using createChildContext() and maybe controlsDescendantBindings, but I'm not really sure.

Any thoughts? I'll continue to update this, because it seems like dynamic bootstrap tooltips would be a common idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that the update binding isn't firing, because it doesn't have a dependency on the properties that you are trying to update (i.e. firstName and address);

Normally you can delegate these properties to a new binding and let knockout automatically handle the dependency tracking.  However, in this case, you're actually returning a string, so the element's automatic binding can't be used.  A string is necessary, because that's how the tooltip works.  If it could dynamically read from a DOM element, then the automatic bindings would work, but because it requires a HTML string, there's no way for the bindings to affect that.

Couple of options that I see:

**1. Automatically create a dependency on the properties used by the template.**  This can be done by isolating the template view model (data) as seen in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tMbs5/13/

```
//create a dependency for each observable property in the data object
for(var prop in templateData)
    if( templateData.hasOwnProperty(prop) && ko.isObservable(templateData[prop]))
        templateData[prop]();
```

**2. Instead of using an DOM-based template, use ko.computed to generate the template inside your view model.**  This will automatically create the dependencies as needed.
See this fiddle for an example of that:  http://jsfiddle.net/tMbs5/12/

```
var vm = {
    firstName: ko.observable('Initial Name'),
    address: ko.observable('55 Walnut Street, #3'),
    changeTooltip: function () {
        this.firstName('New Name');
    }
};

vm.tooltipHtml = ko.computed(function () {
    return "<h2>" + vm.firstName() + "</h2>" +
        "<span>" + vm.address() + "</span>";
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

note: In both fiddles, I have refactored things a tiny bit - mostly for simplification

Comment: Thanks, I like v1 a bit better because I was trying to keep the DOM out of the VM. Especially because my real example, not watered down to a firstName & address property is quite a bit larger.

Comment: I wanted to ad that your solution of keeping track of the properties is nice. I was trying to do something similar, from within the custom bindingHandler, but got stuck.

Comment: I have a new JSFiddle up: http://jsfiddle.net/tMbs5/14/ that will show that the Name can actually change on consecutive databinding operations.