# Custom Binding for Foundations Tooltip in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, zurb-foundation

I am trying to figure out a way of adding a custom binder for foundation's tooltip in knockout like it is done for bootstrap in this example.

[Custom KnockoutJS bindingHandler for dynamic Bootstrap Tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569217/custom-knockoutjs-bindinghandler-for-dynamic-bootstrap-tooltips)

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Writing an entire binding handler is a bit broad for Stack Overflow.  According to the [foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html#adding-new-tooltip-content-after-page-load), it seems that you just have to call `$(document).foundation()` after an update, so I guess that would feature somewhere in your binding handler.  Perhaps it could be done on a more specific element too.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement an update function, an init function, or both depending on the behaviour you require.

A complete walkthrough with a worked example is provided on (surprise, surprise) http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

You got the downvotes (not from me) because you didn't make the slightest attempt to find this for yourself.